# Iteration with data from a csv file (8760 time steps)

Tags: r, for-loop, iteration

i have a csv file in which there are 8760 data points with heating and cooling loads of a building.
I wrote a function that should take the heating and cooling loads of that time step (1,2,3,4...8760) and wheather the heating/cooling is enought should write out how much of the loads in that time step are left. I basically want to check whether i need more heating/cooling power in that hour.
How do i correctly define the for iteration for this? Havent used RStudio in some time and cant get it to work....

In Short:

1. Take Qh_n (heating load) and Qc_n(cooling load) from the csv for the first Time Step 1.
2. Run function and write out Qc_sp and Qh_sp for time step 1 (remaining loads if necessary)
3. Take QH_n and Qc_n from Time Step 2
4. Run function and write out Qc_sp and Qh_sp for time step 2
5. iterate through all 8760 time steps...

```
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# @Werte einlesen
# # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
weather <- read.table("INPUT.csv" , header=F, sep=";", dec=".", skip=1)
Qh_n    <- weather[,4]      # Heizlast 
Qc_n    <- weather[,5]      # Kühllast 
# Randbedingungen
jaz  = 4 # 
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Energie
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ENERGIE <- function(Qcrest,Qhrest)
{ 
epl = 2640    
ent_ep = 90    
ert_ep = 150   
#  
Qhgeo = (Qh/jaz)*(jaz-1)
qh_ep = ent_ep*epl 
Qhgeo - qh_ep = Qhrest  
if (Qhrest >  0) Qh_sp = (Qhrest*jaz)/(jaz-1)
else if (Qhrest <  0) Qh_sp = 0
#  
Qcgeo = Qc/jaz*(jaz+1)
qc_ep = ert_ep*epl
Qcgeo - qc_ep = Qcrest 
if (Qcrest > 0) Qc_sp = (Qcrest*jaz)/(jaz+1)
else if (Qhrest <  0) Qc_sp = 0
list(qh_ep,qc_ep,Qhrest,Qh_sp,Qcrest,Qc_sp)
}
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Startwerte und Initialisierung
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Qc        <<- 0
Qh        <<- 0

# Zeitschleife

i.test = 1:8760 

for (i in i.test)
{ 
# @ENERGIE
  ENERGIE.res <- ENERGIE(Qh_n=Qh[i],Qc_n=Qc[i])

# @Ausgabevariablen
  ENERGIE.Qhrest[i]        <- ENERGIE.res$Qhrest
  ENERGIE.Qcrest[i]        <- ENERGIE.res$Qcrest
  ENERGIE.Qh[i]            <- ENERGIE.res$Qh
  ENERGIE.Qc[i]            <- ENERGIE.res$Qc
  ENERGIE.Qhsp[i]          <- ENERGIE.res$Qhsp
  ENERGIE.Qcsp[i]          <- ENERGIE.res$Qcsp
  }

data.out <- data.frame(cbind(TIME=i.test,AT,Qhrest,Qh_sp,Qcrest,Qc_sp))

write.csv2(data.out,file="OUTPUT.csv")
```

Thank you for your help :)

In Short:

1. Take Qh_n (heating load) and Qc_n(cooling load) from the csv for the first Time Step 1.
2. Run function and write out Qc_sp and Qh_sp for time step 1 (remaining loads if necessary)
3. Take QH_n and Qc_n from Time Step 2
4. Run function and write out Qc_sp and Qh_sp for time step 2
5. iterate through all 8760 time steps...

Comment: You've got a few things going on here: 
1. Your function has the wrong inputs. You say your function needs "Qcrest" and "Qhrest" as inputs but it appears those are calculated within the function. 
2. Additionally, you although you define your function in terms of “Qcrest” and “Qhrest”, when you call your function you say “Qh_n” and “Qc_n.”
3. Qhgeo - qh_ep = Qhrest line should be Qhrest = Qhgeo - qh_ep since you're calculating Qhrest. The same goes for the line with Qcrest 
4. Your if/else statements are missing "}" 
5. Variable "AT" is undefined

Comment: 6. You try to iterate through Qc and Qh via Qc[i] and Qh[i] but you defined those as a just being “0”

Comment: Additionally, you likely don't need iteration since R is vectorized. If Qc_n and Qh_n are what are input into your function and your output is the same number of observations, you should be able to supply those as inputs. For example if you define your function in terms of Qc and Qh you could do ENERGIE(Qc= Qc_n, Qh= Qh_n).

Comment: 7. In one if/else statement it says Qhrest < 0 when I believe it should say Qcrest < 0
8. It is ambiguous what to do if Qcrest or Qhrest = 0 in your else/if statements.

Comment: I'd also suggest removing the "rstudio" tag from your question since your question pertains to R code, not the graphical environment you're running the code in (RStudio). R is the coding language, RStudio is what's called an integrated development environment (IDE).

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked your function a bit so it is vectorized over all of your data and outputs a dataframe. You'll need to decide if the if/else statments should be gretater than or greater than equal to to decide what's assigned if Qhrest or Qcrest are 0.

```
Qh_n    <- rnorm(n = 8760, mean = 30, sd = 5)     # Fake data 
Qc_n    <- rnorm(n = 8760, mean = 50, sd = 3)      # Fake data  
# Randbedingungen
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Energie
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ENERGIE <- function(Qc,Qh)
{ 
  jaz  = 4 
  epl = 2640    
  ent_ep = 90    
  ert_ep = 150   
  #  
  Qhgeo = (Qh/jaz)*(jaz-1)
  qh_ep = ent_ep*epl 
  Qhrest = Qhgeo - qh_ep 
  Qh_sp = ifelse(Qhrest >  0, (Qhrest*jaz)/(jaz-1), 0) #Decide if this should be > or >=
  Qcgeo = Qc/jaz*(jaz+1)
  qc_ep = ert_ep*epl
  Qcrest = Qcgeo - qc_ep  
  Qc_sp = ifelse(Qcrest > 0, (Qcrest*jaz)/(jaz+1), 0) #Decide if this should be > or >=
  ENERGIE.res<- data.frame(TIME= 1:length(Qhrest), Qhrest=Qhrest,Qh_sp=Qh_sp,Qcrest=Qcrest,Qc_sp=Qc_sp)
  return(ENERGIE.res)
}

data.out<- ENERGIE(Qc = Qc_n, Qh= Qh_n)
```